# Where to put executables used by daemon processes in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, daemon

I am making a daemon for Mac OSX. So my daemon will run an executable.
Can you tell me where is the best place for the executable to be placed. I want this to be run for every user.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

It's not so much your daemon, as its property list (plist) which matters. launchd will enumerate and execute the daemons in /System/Library/LaunchDaemons and /Library/LaunchDaemons for all users. A la Apple, you are supposed to use the latter for 3rd party plists. The plist's "Program" key can point to your daemon, which can be anywhere. Bear in mind you do need root privileges to write to either folder, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can create HelperTools folder in `/Library/Application Support/` and place your daemon in HelperTools folder.